# I can't install pyaudio on Windows 11?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, pip, pyaudio

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jd1xu2pm'
       cwd: C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-84dt8r3e\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7zj32_tv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-84dt8r3e\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-84dt8r3e\\pyaudio_93a7719f57d74959a2374b9d3da284f9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7zj32_tv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20%5bpyaudio%5d%20error%3a%20Microsoft%20Visual%20C%2b%2b%2014.0%20is%20required, https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20error%3a%20Microsoft%20Visual%20C%2b%2b%2014.0%20is%20required

Answer (score 1):

the error is self-explanatory:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

did you already install `Microsoft VS C++ build tools` ?

link to download: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019